# vehicle cmd topic subscription and message error display

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys, Anyone has any ideas on this please.

```
rosmsg show autoware_msgs/VehicleCmd
Unable to load msg [autoware_msgs/VehicleCmd]: Cannot locate message [VehicleCmd]: unknown package [autoware_msgs] on search path [{'rosconsole': ['/opt/ros/melodic/share/rosconsole/msg'], 'catkin': ['/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/msg'],
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354419/vehicle-cmd--topic-subscription-and-message-error-display/) by [sneibus](https://answers.ros.org/users/51953/sneibus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The autoware_msgs` package is missing. Did you source the ROS workspace where this package is installed? Otherwise you will probably need to compile it

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sneibus](https://answers.ros.org/users/51953/sneibus/) on 2020-06-15**:
and how do you do that please :)

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2020-07-10**:
On every terminal that you use, you need to change to the autoware installation folder (probably `~/autoware.ai` and then run `source install/setup.bash`